# What does .sum( ) do specifically in this situation?

Tags: python, pytorch, sum, autograd

Usually when I've seen the sum function used, it has taken an argument within it's parentheses. What exactly does it do in the following, and what is the point of it?

```
a = torch.randn(2, 2)
a = ((a * 3) / (a - 1))
print(a.requires_grad)
a.requires_grad_(True)
print(a.requires_grad)
b = (a * a).sum()
print(b)
print(b.grad_fn)
```

Comment: That's the `sum` _method_, being called on whatever `a * a` returns (a Tensor, by the look of it: https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.Tensor.sum.html).

Comment: It's just another way of writing `b=torch.sum(a*a)` (in an object-oriented style). Same way you can write `a + a` as `a.add(a)`

Comment: There are some imports missing from this code for more people to be able to make sense of it.